# Add pie charts on specific lat long positions when drilled down on a World Map - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a world map. When I click into Asia/North America,  it drills down and shows me the countries. However, I want to show a pie chart on specific countries with the data. I do see just one 1 piechart instead of multiple piecharts. How do I use the lat/lon to position them? Also, when I drill up, I expect that the piecharts are not visible. Thanks.

This is my code.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Highcharts, { geojson } from 'highcharts/highmaps';
import drilldown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown';
import dataModule from 'highcharts/modules/data';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import topology from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world-continents.topo.json';

function extractLatLonAndKey(chartData) {
  let result = [];

  for (let continent in chartData) {
    // Push continent data
    result.push([
      chartData[continent].lat,
      chartData[continent].lon,
      continent,
    ]);
  }

  return result;
}

function extractCountries(data) {
  let countries = [];

  for (let continent in data) {
    for (let country in data[continent].data) {
      countries.push(country);
    }
  }

  return countries;
}

const chartData: Record<string, any> = {
  'North America': {
    lat: 54.526,
    lon: -105.2551,
    data: {
      Canada: {
        lat: 56.1304,
        lon: -106.3468,
        data: [
          { name: 'Chrome', y: 73.24 },
          { name: 'Edge', y: 12.93 },
          { name: 'Firefox', y: 4.73 },
          { name: 'Safari', y: 2.5 },
          { name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 1.65 },
          { name: 'Other', y: 4.93 },
        ],
      },
      'United States of America': {
        lat: 37.0902,
        lon: -95.7129,
        data: [
          { name: 'Chrome', y: 73.24 },
          { name: 'Edge', y: 12.93 },
          { name: 'Firefox', y: 4.73 },
          { name: 'Safari', y: 2.5 },
          { name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 1.65 },
          { name: 'Other', y: 4.93 },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  Asia: {
    lat: 34.0479,
    lon: 100.6197,
    data: {
      India: {
        lat: 20.5937,
        lon: 78.9629,
        data: [
          { name: 'Chrome', y: 73.24 },
          { name: 'Edge', y: 12.93 },
          { name: 'Firefox', y: 4.73 },
          { name: 'Safari', y: 2.5 },
          { name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 1.65 },
          { name: 'Other', y: 4.93 },
        ],
      },
      China: {
        lat: 35.8617,
        lon: 104.1954,
        data: [
          { name: 'Chrome', y: 73.24 },
          { name: 'Edge', y: 12.93 },
          { name: 'Firefox', y: 4.73 },
          { name: 'Safari', y: 2.5 },
          { name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 1.65 },
          { name: 'Other', y: 4.93 },
        ],
      },
      Russia: {
        lat: 61.524,
        lon: 105.3188,
        data: [
          { name: 'Chrome', y: 73.24 },
          { name: 'Edge', y: 12.93 },
          { name: 'Firefox', y: 4.73 },
          { name: 'Safari', y: 2.5 },
          { name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 1.65 },
          { name: 'Other', y: 4.93 },
        ],
      },
      'United Arab Emirates': {
        lat: 23.4241,
        lon: 53.8478,
        data: [
          { name: 'Chrome', y: 73.24 },
          { name: 'Edge', y: 12.93 },
          { name: 'Firefox', y: 4.73 },
          { name: 'Safari', y: 2.5 },
          { name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 1.65 },
          { name: 'Other', y: 4.93 },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
};

if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
  drilldown(Highcharts);
  dataModule(Highcharts);
}

let data = typeof Highcharts === 'object' ? geojson(topology) : [];

// Set drilldown pointers
data.forEach(function (el, i) {
  el.drilldown = `custom/${el.properties['name']
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(' ', '-')}`;
  el.value = i;
  el.color = 'white'; // Non-random bogus data
});

const dur = 700,
  disableZoom = false;

const drilldownFunc = async function (this: Highcharts.Chart, e: any) {
  if (!Object.keys(chartData).includes(e.point.name)) {
    return;
  }
  if (!e.seriesOptions) {
    const chart = this,
      mapKey = `${e.point.drilldown}`;

    // Handle error, the timeout is cleared on success
    let fail = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!Highcharts.maps[mapKey]) {
        chart.showLoading(`
                    <i class="icon-frown"></i>
                    Failed loading ${e.point.name}
                `);
        fail = setTimeout(() => {
          chart.hideLoading();
        }, 1000);
      }
    }, 3000);

    // Show the Font Awesome spinner
    chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-3x"></i>');

    // Load the drilldown map
    const topology = await fetch(
      `https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/${mapKey}.topo.json`
    ).then((response) => response.json());

    const data = Highcharts.geojson(topology);

    data.forEach((d, i) => {
      d.value = i;
      d.color = 'white';
    });

    const mappointSeries = this.series.find(
      (series: any) => series.name === 'Regions'
    );
    if (mappointSeries) {
      mappointSeries.remove(false); // remove the mappoint series without redrawing immediately
    }

    const drillDownData = chartData[e.point.name].data;

    Object.keys(drillDownData).forEach((d) => {
      chart.addSeries(
        {
          id: `pieChart-${d}`,
          type: 'pie',
          name: d,
          zIndex: 6, // Keep pies above connector lines
          minSize: 15,
          data: drillDownData[d].data,
        },
        false
      );
    });

    // Apply the recommended map view if any
    chart.mapView.update(
      Highcharts.merge(
        {
          insets: undefined,
        },
        topology.objects.default['hc-recommended-mapview']
      ),
      !disableZoom
    );

    // Hide loading and add series
    chart.hideLoading();
    clearTimeout(fail);
    chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
      name: e.point.name,
      data,
      custom: {
        mapView: topology.objects.default['hc-recommended-mapview'],
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        format: '{point.name}',
      },
      type: 'map',
    });
  }
};

const drillup = function (this: any, e: any) {
  const chart = this;
  const pieChartName = extractCountries(chartData);
  const pieChartIds = pieChartName.map((d) => `pieChart-${d}`);

  console.log('pieChartIds', pieChartIds);
  chart.series.forEach(function (series: any) {
    if (series.options && pieChartIds.includes(series.options.id)) {
      series.remove(false);
    }
  });

  if (e.seriesOptions.custom && e.seriesOptions.custom.mapView) {
    e.target.mapView.update(
      Highcharts.merge(
        {
          insets: undefined,
        },
        e.seriesOptions.custom.mapView
      ),
      false
    );
  }

  const mappointData = extractLatLonAndKey(chartData);

  chart.addSeries(
    {
      name: 'Regions',
      color: '#d10a11',
      data: mappointData,
      type: 'mappoint',
    },
    false
  );

  chart.redraw();
};

const WorldMap = () => {
  const chartComponentRef = useRef<HighchartsReact.RefObject>(null);

  const mapView = {
    projection: {
      name: 'Miller',
      rotation: [0],
    },
  };

  const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      events: {
        drilldown: drilldownFunc as any,
        drillup,
        load: function (e) {
          const chart = this;
          chart.series.forEach((series) => {
            series.points.forEach((point) => {
              if (!Object.keys(chartData).includes(point.name)) {
                point.update({
                  events: {
                    mouseOver() {
                      return false;
                    },
                  },
                  marker: {
                    states: {
                      hover: {
                        enabled: false,
                      },
                    },
                  },
                });
              }
            });
          });
        },
      },
      backgroundColor: '#b6dcf4',
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Highcharts Map Drilldown',
    },

    mapView,

    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },

    plotOptions: {
      map: {
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: '#EEDD66',
          },
        },
      },
      mappoint: {
        keys: ['lat', 'lon', 'name'],
        marker: {
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColor: '#000',
          symbol: 'mapmarker',
          radius: 8,
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      pie: {
        size: 80,
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        innerSize: '50%',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          connectorColor: 'silver',
        },
      },
    },

    series: [
      {
        data,
        allAreas: true,
        name: 'World Continents',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.name}',
        },
        custom: {
          mapView,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Regions',
        color: '#d10a11',
        data: extractLatLonAndKey(chartData),
        type: 'mappoint',
      },
    ] as any,

    drilldown: {
      breadcrumbs: {
        floating: true,
        relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
      },
      activeDataLabelStyle: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        textOutline: '1px #000000',
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={options}
      constructorType={'mapChart'}
      ref={chartComponentRef}
    />
  );
};

export default WorldMap;
```

This is my stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-irjggg?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Please advice.

Comment: Please check out this demo; it should work as you've described: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-llw8vy?file=src%2FApp.tsx